# Msysgit pushing with the wrong account

Tags: git, github, msysgit

I have a github account that is public, and I have a different account for different projects and such, but whenever I commit to a repository made by the other account, I seem to commit as my original account. If that was confusing I will provide an example:

`Bob` is my Github account for Java Projects

`Dave` is my Github account for Python projects.

I do `$ git commit origin master` (the origin is setup correctly to `Dave`'s repository)

THEN I input `Dave`'s username and password, BUT the commits page shows that `Bob` commited, what the heck is going on?!?!

I really need to know this because this is very bad for me.

EDIT: Another thing, is that `Bob` has nothing to do with the repository (not even in the contributors list) He shouldn't even be able to push any changes!! Really confused on this one ;-;

Answer (score 0):

git authentication isn't related to commit authoring - ie, the username & password you use to get access to the repo is **not** related to the username & email in the commits you are pushing.

That's a feature *by design*.

The user displayed on GitHub's commits is the commits' author and commiter, not the user who pushed that commits. You should change your `user.name` and `user.email` on your local repository's `config`, like:

`$ git config user.name 'Dave'
$ git config user.email 'dave@example.com'`

And your new commits *in that repository* will have that info updated.

There's more relevant info in GitHub's help [Why are my commits linked to the wrong user?](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user/)